# Python class method executing multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, oop, subclass, super

I am new to OOP and class inheritance in Python. I am working with a Pandas dataframe, extracting information from a "cell", removing the information from the cell in which it was found, and putting the saved information in a new column.

I have four classes, each of which inherit from the preceding one in the following list. The base class, `Reader` reads in the dataframe, `Extractor` uses RegEx to find matches to technical information, `Categories` houses information on which `Extractor` methods to return for a given category, and `Looper` reads through the dataframe with [iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), determines which `Categories` methods to use for a given row, and assigns `Extractor` values to list indices that are returned as dataframe columns.

The issue that I am having is that my `Extractor` methods are getting called  more than I would like them to/more than they should, meaning that with each subsequent call, the likelihood of a given method finding the technical information reduces because of the removal operation. I do not know if this is because the act of pointing to the method with `self` invokes it, if I am using [super()](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) incorrectly, or if there are redundancies in my code that I do not understand because of my limited experience.

I have been reading about [subclassing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas) and am curious if anyone sees a viable solution there or if the problem has a much simpler solution.

Below is a sample of my program with print statements and their output.

```
class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        super(Reader, self).__init__()
        self.df = dataframe.replace({r'[^\x00-\x7F]+':''}, regex=True, 
        inplace = True) # Remove non-ascii characters
        self.df = dataframe.applymap(str) # Necessary for RegEx operations
        self.category = self.df.columns.get_loc('Category')
        self.Name = self.df.columns.get_loc('Name')
        self.Desc = self.df.columns.get_loc('Description')

class Extractor(Reader):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Extractor, self).__init__(dataframe)

        self.cellNames = []
        self.cellDesc = []
        for idx, cell in self.df.iterrows():
             self.cellNames.append(self.df.iat[index, self.Name])
             self.cellDesc.append(self.df.iat[index, self.Desc])

    def getDiameter(self, compilers, idx): # Compilers is a list of RegEx compilers
        diameterValue = None
        for compiler in compilers:
            matchList = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(compiler, self.cellNames[idx])]
            try:
                match = matchList[0] # finditer's first full match
            except IndexError:
                if compiler == compilers[-1]:
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            if len(matchlist) > 0: # I was getting empty matchLists running test cases
                self.cellNames[idx]  = cellNames[idx].replace(match, '')
                diameterValue = match
                print 1, diameterValue
                return diameterValue
        # If no match, do the same thing but for cellDesc
        # If no match, diameterValue still == None
        print 2, diameterValue
        return diameterValue


class Categories(Extractor):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Categories, self).__init__()

    def some_rules(self):
        print 3, self.getDiameter(compilers, idx)
        return self.getDiameter(compilers, idx)


class Looper(Categories):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Looper, self).__init__()

    def doLoop(self):
        diameterCol = # empty list the same size as a dataframe column
        global idx
        for idx, row in self.df.iterrows():
            if 'some category' in self.df.iat[idx, self.category]:
               print 4, self.some_rules()[0] # I think this is pointing to Extractor.getDiameter. I would like this to be the only pointer that invokes the method.
               diameterCol[idx] = some_rules()[0]
        self.df['Diameter'] = diameterCol
        return self.df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataframe = pd.read_excel(infileName, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
    myData = Reader(dataframe)
    Looper().doLoop()
```

And the output (for one row):

```
3 diameterValue # Primary and preferred RegEx match
1 diameterValue2 # Secondary RegEx match, no more after this
2 None
3 None
2 None
4 None
2 None
3 None
2 None
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating each class?

Comment: What's the `__main__` function?? Your code wouldn't produce *any output*, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: My apologies, I have since edited to include instantiation information.

Comment: You may find the discussion here enlightening: [Object Oriented Programming is Bad](https://youtu.be/QM1iUe6IofM?t=1m). (I don't subscribe to the *prescriptions*, but the identification of the problems and failures of OOP are spot on, in my opinion.) Inheritance is *very* rarely used in practice anymore.

Comment: That was incredibly helpful to understand inheritance and its shortcomings with regards to proper encapsulation. Thank you @jpmc26!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by axing `Categories` which was making redundant calls to `Extractor` methods. Instead I am calling those methods directly with their arguments in `Looper`.